# IDA: How to use REFINFO_SUBTRACT in OpOffEx(...)

Tags: python, offset, subtraction, ida

I am disassembling an AVR (microcontroller) hex file using IDA (Interactive DisAssembler). I try to convert some operands type to offset using `OpOffEx(...)` idapython script command.

```
OpOffEx(ea, 1, REF_LOW8+REFINFO_SUBTRACT, target, base, tdelta)
overflowError: in method 'op_offset', argument 3 of type 'reftype_t'
```

It almost works, except when I use `REFINFO_SUBTRACT` as `reftype` for negative offsets. It don't accept any value>=0x100 at all.

So how can I set this flag in idapython?